# Adding "AllowUpload" to the MyCart page in the Acumatica Customer Portal

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add the ability to upload order lines into "Mycart" on the customer portal via excel or csv.  I customized the screen and set AllowUpload to True.  The button shows up on the grid, but throws an error as soon as I choose a file and click the upload button on the little file upload screen.  The error I get is "Error during file upload: Error #103: View DocumentDetails $ImportContentBag doesn't exist."
It appears that this form hasn't been set up for File upload.  Is it possible to create this capacity.  Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [PXImport] attribute on the View defnition in your BLC.

Comment: I added this to the view and instead of erroring out when I click the upload button, I get nothing.  The upload screen just closes, nothing in the trace.

Comment: public class InventoryCardMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<InventoryCardMaint>
    {
        [PXImport(typeof(PortalCardLines))]
        public PXSelect<PortalCardLines> DocumentDetails;
    }

Comment: Turns out I should have been using PortalCardLine.  Thanks for the help!